# Algorithms for multiplication and addition by modulo $p$ without overflow of some larger modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, numerical-methods, algorithms, computer-science

I'm wondering if there is a simple algorithm for multiplication / addition of two $n$ bit numbers by modulo $p$, where all steps are done with $n$ bit numbers (so no number ever overflows / goes beyond $2^n$).

Comment: You can compute $ab = x2^n  + y$ where $x$ and $y$ are $n$ bit numbers, then do basic long division on $x$ followed by long division on $y$.  If what you actually had in mind was computing modular multiplication without overflow without using some kind of looping-construct, then that's offtopic for this website, but see https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/96759?f0a28=1 or search engine using keywords "modular multiplication overflow".

Answer (score 1):

See [Montgomery modular multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication) and Montgomery reduction in the linked article.